# pass byte[] , file parameter to a method java

Tags: java, methods

I m confused to how to pass byte array and file to a method in Java :
when I call enregistre method : enregistre(img3File, file3) and enregistre(img4File, file4)  enregistre(img5File, file5) , it doesn t upload  the file to the database, but when I call the part of program without method( I repeat the code with :img2File and file2 ) it worked, I dont want to repeat the code 5 times, I beleive there are a solution , help me to figure out what is wrong when I call the method please.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String add (
               @RequestParam("photos") MultipartFile file,
               @RequestParam("photos2") MultipartFile file2,
               @RequestParam("photos3") MultipartFile file3,
               @RequestParam("photos4") MultipartFile file4,
               @RequestParam("photos5") MultipartFile file5)


    {
               byte[] img1File=null;

                try {
//////////////////////// part1
                     img1File= file.getBytes();
                     BufferedOutputStream stream;
                     stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("ben1")));

                     stream.write(img1File);
                     stream.close();
//////////////////// end part 1 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 // here I repeat the code and I don t want to repeat it    
                byte[] img2File=null;

                try {
////////////////////////  part 2 
                     img2File= file2.getBytes();
                     BufferedOutputStream stream;
                     stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("ben1")));

                     stream.write(img2File);
                     stream.close();
////////////////////////end   part 2 

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte[] img3File=null;
                enregistre(img3File, file3);

                byte[] img4File=null;
                enregistre(img4File, file4);

                byte[] img5File=null;
                enregistre(img5File, file5);

        Annonce annonce=new Annonce();

        annonce.setPhotos(img1File);
        annonce.setPhotos2(img2File);
        annonce.setPhotos3(img3File);
        annonce.setPhotos4(img4File);
        annonce.setPhotos5(img5File);

        annoncedao.save(annonce);
        return "SuccessAddAnnonce";

    // method
  public void enregistre(byte[] imgFile,MultipartFile file)
    {


        try {
            imgFile= file.getBytes();

             BufferedOutputStream stream;
             stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("ben1")));

             stream.write(imgFile);
             stream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing a null `byte[]` to `enregistre` and then re-assigning the parameter inside the method?

Comment: I forget to delete that line  to asign null, but it doesn t change the result

Answer (score 0):

Look at what your `enregistre` method does:

```
BufferedOutputStream stream;
stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("ben1")));
stream.write(imgFile);
stream.close();
```

If you call that method multiple times, it will write to the *same file* multiple times. There's no point in that - you'll just end up with the file containing the data for the last call. Note that the method doesn't do anything with a database - it just writes a file. You haven't explained to us where the code that *does* write to the database is, but presumably it's reading from that file at some point.

(Aside from that, the first parameter of the method is completely useless, as you immediately reassign it. This code has some serious issues in terms of code hygiene, but I've focused just on what you were asking.)

Comment: if you look to the code , I put bloc of code between comments  part 1  and part 2 , those blocs works fine . I just don t want to repeat the same code. to answer your question about database :  I m using Spring data , so this lines  'annonce.setPhotos(img1File);
        annonce.setPhotos2(img2File);
        annonce.setPhotos3(img3File);
        annonce.setPhotos4(img4File);
        annonce.setPhotos5(img5File);

        annoncedao.save(annonce);'   save to database and it s works for imgfile 1 and 2 .